# I need MySQL datatypes mapping to .net (CLR) datatypes

Tags: .net, mysql, types, clr

Does anyone have a complete table of MySQL datatypes mapping to .Net (CLR) datatypes. There are question on the same topic on StackOverflow but the information given is inconsistent rather useless.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a mapping to Java types, it is easy to convert this to .NET mapping...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip: You may easily create the mapping table by creating a MySql table with MySqltyped columns and then retrieving it from the .net provider. Then just introspect the .net type (in the DataReader or DataTable) of the column.

Answer (score 0):

I found this mapping, seems to be from 2013 ([blogspot.dk](http://elaanet.blogspot.dk/2013/02/mapping-net-data-types-to-mysql-data.html))

[image: mapping]

And I can add that MySql **tinyint(1)** is mapped automatically to **boolean** in .Net